# Changing Button state with 2nd Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to change the State of one Button to NORMAL by pressing another Button.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar
from tkinter.constants import DISABLED

LARGE_FONT =('Verdana',12)

class Auswertung(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Datenwahl,):
            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(Datenwahl)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames [cont] 
        frame.tkraise() 

    def enable_button2(self):
        self.button2.config(sate = NORMAL)


class Datenwahl(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,)



        label=tk.Label(self, text='Start Page', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10 ,sticky= 'ew')

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text= 'Visit Page 1', 
                            command= lambda : controller.enable_button2())
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text= 'Visit Page 2', state=DISABLED,
                            command= lambda : controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


app = Auswertung()
app.mainloop()
```

this is the whole Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\OneDrive\Dokumente\Privat\Python lernen\nested\tested.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    command= lambda : controller.enable_button2())
  File "C:\Users\pasca\OneDrive\Dokumente\Privat\Python lernen\nested\tested.py", line 34, in enable_button2
    self.button2.config(sate = NORMAL)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'button2'
```

I have tried different approaches to the Problem but mostly it either gives the same error or it just plainly does nothing to the button state. Im Looking forward to our Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating local variables, you need to make your `button2` a class attribute of `Datenwahl` by adding `self`:

```
class Datenwahl(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,)
        ...
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text= 'Visit Page 2', state="disabled",
                            command= lambda : controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        self.button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Then you can access `button2` in your instance of `Auswertung`:

```
class Auswertung(tk.Tk):

    ...

    def enable_button2(self):
        self.frames[Datenwahl].button2.config(state = "normal")
```